# How to pass parameters to HttpResponseRequest elsewhere than in the url in Django

Tags: django, url, django-context

I'm trying to code a form in Django that redirect to itself, the display changing according to what you entered in the form. To do so, I retrieve the POST data in the backend and want to display a message this way: `{% if message %} {{ message }} {% endif %}`
The problem is how to pass the `message` argument.

I know I could use

```
#urls.py
url(r'^form/(?P<message>)$', 'app.form', name='form')

#views.py
...my_message...
return HttpResponseRedirect(reverse('app:form', args=(my_message,))
```

but it would display the message in the url, which isn't suitable for my purpose.
Would you know how I could do it and stay hidden in my backend, something like

```
#views.py
return HttpResponseRedirect(reverse('app:form'), {'message': my_message})
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use [sessions](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.5/topics/http/sessions/) to store the message - or even, the built-in [messages framework](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.5/ref/contrib/messages/).

Comment: Thank you for your answer ! I was trying to find a way to pass some kind of meta-data server side but if I understood well this isn't the way django works in this example. I'll investigate the sessions and message framework, thanks for the tip !